# How to handle onPause / onResume for GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es

When a GlSurfaceView is embedded in a layout, e.g.,

```
  <FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/framelay"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <com.nelsondev.myha3ogl.M3View
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
  </FrameLayout>
```

Then when the layout is inflated it gets constructed automatically using the constructor with the signature: *GLSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)*.   So it's not literally declared or instantiated in the Activity class.

The Android documentation says that the Activity's onPause/onResume must call the SurfaceView's onPause/onResume.    How should I do this?  I.e., how can the Activity which inflated the layout get access to the GlSurfaceView object to make those calls?

**Edit:**  This is for Android 2.2

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your XML layout, give your SurfaceView a name by adding the name attribute:

```
<com.nelsondev.myha3ogl.M3View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/my_surfaceView1"/>
```

Next, override onPause and onResume in your activity, find the view by using `findViewById(R.id.my_surfaceView1);` and then call onPause and onResume on your surfaceView:

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    com.nelsondev.myha3ogl.M3View myView = (com.nelsondev.myha3ogl.M3View)findViewById(R.id.my_surfaceView1);

    myView.onPause();

    super.onPause();

}
```

Finally, in your implementation of your surface view, override onPause() / onResume() and put any code you need to do when your activity pauses / resumes in there. Remember also to call super.onPause() / super.onResume() in the surface view

---

Edit: just to clarify, you can use `findViewById()` method on any ViewGroup object to find child views inside that viewgroup:

```
MyActivity extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){

        FrameLayout myFrameLayout = (FrameLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.graphics, null, false);
        TextView myView = (TextView)myFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        if(myView!=null){
            myView.setText("about to be removed");
            myFrameLayout.removeView(myView);
        }

        setContentView(myFrameLayout);


    }
}
```

Or `findViewById()` is also a method in Activity, which will find any view in the layout you set using `setContentView();`

```
MyActivity extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        setContentView(R.layout.graphics);
        // where the xml file in your question is called graphics.xml    
        com.nelsondev.myha3ogl.M3View myGLSurfaceView = (com.nelsondev.myha3ogl.M3View)findViewById(R.id.my_surfaceView1);
        FrameLayout myFrameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.framelay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I've used findViewById many times for buttons and edit controls, etc, but I didn't realise I could use it with my own custom classes like this.  It worked perfectly; thanks again!